# Using SqlDataAdapter.Update and RowUpdating to update a database from a gridview

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am posting this question after reading other similar questions about my problem but not really understanding how I can use the information.

I have been mainly writing this code to see how I can use SqlDataAdapters to update a database from a GridView.

I am writing my GridView in my aspx page as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Clients" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="labelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textboxName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in my code behind file I am writing the following code (Database is just a class to connect to my database...):

```
Database database = new Database();
database.open_connection();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, database.dbConnection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dataTable);

SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

Clients.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
Clients.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(this.grid_view_page_index_changing);
Clients.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(this.grid_view_sorting);
Clients.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(this.row_editing);
Clients.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(this.row_updating);
Clients.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(this.row_canceling_edit);
Clients.AllowPaging = true;
Clients.PageSize = 25;
Clients.AllowSorting = true;
Clients.DataSource = dataTable;
Clients.DataBind();

database.close_connection();
```

This all works fine so far; The GridView Sorting, Editing, RowCancellingEdit, PageIndexChanging functions etc work as they should do.

My problem is when I call the RowUpdating function.

What I want to do is use the `adapter.Update()` function to update the database.

It doesn't throw any errors with my current code, but it doesn't update the database either.

As soon as I click update, the edit text box from my GridView disappears and I am left with the original value before trying to edit it.

This is my `row_updating()` function:

```
public void row_updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) {
    GridViewRow gvr = gridView.Rows[Clients.EditIndex];

    TextBox txt = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("textboxName");
    e.NewValues["Name"] = txt.Text;

    adapter.Update((DataTable)Clients.DataSource);

    Clients.EditIndex = -1;
    Clients.DataBind();
}
```

I can't figure out why it won't update the database (Probably because I am doing it completely wrong)

I have seen stuff around the internet that mentions a `EndEdit()` function, but I'm not sure if that applies here.

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong and why my database won't update it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `row_updating()` functions code which isn't of much relevence here, but the thing that fixed it for me was making sure I used !Page.IsPostBack

So now my `Page_Load()` functions sets up the GridView and then instead of just binding the data it goes:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
    Clients.DataBind();
}
```

Although it isn't working perfectly, at least it is now updating my database (Which is what this question was about, so I will post a new questions if I can't find a solution to my new problem)

Sometimes it's just the simplest things that cause the most frustrating problems...

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the UpdateCommand for your data adapter. If not then I think you may need to do it to successfully update the data.

Also check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) link:

> If INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statements have not been specified,
>   the Update method generates an
>   exception. However, you can create a
>   SqlCommandBuilder or
>   OleDbCommandBuilder object to
>   automatically generate SQL statements
>   for single-table updates if you set
>   the SelectCommand property of a .NET
>   Framework data provider. Then, any
>   additional SQL statements that you do
>   not set are generated by the
>   CommandBuilder. This generation logic
>   requires key column information to be
>   present in the DataSet. For more
>   information see Generating Commands
>   with CommandBuilders (ADO.NET).
>
> The Update method retrieves rows from
>   the table listed in the first mapping
>   before performing an update. The
>   Update then refreshes the row using
>   the value of the UpdatedRowSource
>   property. Any additional rows returned
>   are ignored.
>
> After any data is loaded back into the
>   DataSet, the OnRowUpdated event is
>   raised, allowing the user to inspect
>   the reconciled DataSet row and any
>   output parameters returned by the
>   command. After a row updates
>   successfully, the changes to that row
>   are accepted.
>
> When using Update, the order of
>   execution is as follows:
>
> ```
> The values in the DataRow are moved to the parameter values.
>
> The OnRowUpdating event is raised.
>
> The command executes.
>
> If the command is set to FirstReturnedRecord, then the first
> ```
>
> returned result is placed in the
>   DataRow.
>
> ```
> If there are output parameters, they are placed in the DataRow.
>
> The OnRowUpdated event is raised.
>
> AcceptChanges is called.
> ```

Comment: I tried using adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(); as they did in the link, but I still get the same results.